# C++ disallow cast to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move

As always with variables which have been `std::move`'d, it is unsafe to use them afterwards.

As I have written a code where I encourage the user to apply `std::move` on various occasions, I want to avoid that it is used in a wrong way, at least in a few crucial places (so to say selectively "protect against Machiavelli").

Therefore, is the following overload of `std::move` a valid way to go? Or would you discourage from using it?

```
struct A
{
     void do_something() const { /* ... whatever ... */ }
};

namespace std
{
    auto move(A& t) noexcept = delete;
    auto move(A const& t) noexcept = delete;
    //possibly the same for volatile qualifier

    //possibly also specialize static_cast<A const&>, static_cast<A&>, etc.
}

// possibly set up another function "my_private_move"
// which I can use exclusively where it is appropriate.

int main()
{
    A a;
    // auto a_moved = std::move(a);      //disallow move of lvalue ref
    a.do_something();                    //otherwise this could be problematic

    A(A{});                             //direct initialization via move constructor is ok
    auto x2 = A{};                      
}
```

Comment: "As always with variables which have been std::move'd, it is unsafe to use them afterwards." Not really. `std::move` doesn't do anything to a variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza: agreed, but if you see a function `f(A&&)` and call it via `A a; f(std::move(a));`, one has to be really cautious.

Comment: But that doesn't make your leading sentence correct.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I guess that's a question of definition, but we both understand, so whatever :)

Comment: @davidhigh "*if you see a function `f(A&&)` and call it via `A a; f(std::move(a));`, one has to be really cautious.*" Why? It looks weird, but is same as `f(A())` unless `a` is used afterwards. How can you know this from `A` or `f` point of view? It's impossible. Also, you can get an rvalue reference or invoke move semantics in other ways. So just blocking selected ones is pretty inconsistent in a very bad way. IMO defending against user is not the way to go. `#define private public`

Comment: It also seems pretty strange that you write code where you encourage the user to apply `std::move`. It sounds like you have a bad design and are going about fixing it the wrong way.

Comment: @luk32: if you see a function taking an rvalue reference, you have to assume that it is moved from it, see [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html). All other would be neglicient. I agree, in reality you usually what's going on inside ...

Comment: @juanchopanza: bad design? probably yes, always. But "encourage" might have been also the wrong word. Basically it is `A a, F(std::move(a));`, not much more :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior, as per [namespace.std]:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it **adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std`** or to a
>   namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
>   for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>   and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

Your use case does not fall under the "otherwise specified" umbrella. Besides being undefined, it's of questionable value... you're disallowing this:

```
A a; 
f(std::move(a)); 
// just don't use a here
```

despite that being potentially a performance improvement over `f(a)`. But the user can still write the cast explicitly to accomplish the same result:

```
f(static_cast<A&&>(a)); // slightly more verbose move
```

Comment: This is why I wrote the "possibly specialize `static_cast`" sentence in the code. This should be allowed, I guess?

Comment: @davidhigh: You can approximate it, but it's silly and pointless to do so. What you want does not make sense.

Comment: @davidhigh `static_cast`, despite looking like a template, is actually a keyword.

Comment: ok, so beside that it might be problematic by design, I understand that there is even no safe way to do it.

Comment: @davidhigh If you want to disallow moving, just `delete` `A(A&& )` and `A& operator=(A&& )`.

Comment: ok, I agree this would be a way to go, but then they are completely out of the game, which is what I wanted to avoid. Or one could alternatively make them private and define some other friend classes which allow their move, or whatever ... thanks.

Comment: by the way: what about deleting the function template specialization of `move<A const&>` instead of adding overloads and delete those? That seems to be safe to me as of "*A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type*", correct? (... Not that it renders the whole approach practical, as there's still `static_cast<A&&>`)

Comment: @davidhigh No. That wouldn't meet the requirements for the original template. That would also prevent you from being able to do lots of things, like `vector<A>`

Comment: Well, technically you can add specializations (as opposed to overloads) of `std::move`, but it's rather pointless, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

> As always with variables which have been std::move'd, it is unsafe to
>   use them afterwards

That's not true at all. It's perfectly safe to use things that have been moved from. There are lots of places where they *must* be used after being moved from by Standard, for example `std::swap` or even just destructing locals.

What you *can't* do is assume that they have any *specific* valid state. But they must have *some* valid state. If you are authoring `A` and it does not abide by these rules, then `A` is broken and should be fixed, rather than band-aiding over the problem.

Comment: I would disagree by my experience: move a `shared_ptr` and try to dereference it afterwards (... without sanity checks). That gives a program crash for me.

Comment: Provided said things have been implemented sensibly (e.g. anything in the standard library.)

Comment: @davidhigh: That is assuming a specific state of the `shared_ptr`- not null, and it therefore violates the rule. null is a valid state of `shared_ptr` and therefore a moved-from `shared_ptr` may be null without violating the laws of move. Anybody assuming that it is not null is in the wrong- there's nothing broken with `shared_ptr` or movement.

Comment: While a good point, this isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, while I understand the implications, this doesn't cure my problem. The user is indifferent whether the program crashes out of a valid state or not. This is what I meant by the (as yet undefined) word "unsafe".

Comment: @Barry: You're right- it renders the question fundamentally obsolete and therefore no answer is required.

Comment: @davidhigh: The solution is not to write bad code that makes unwarranted assumptions. It's not to prevent every possible condition that could occur that has preconditions.

Comment: @davidhigh The user should use the valid state of an object such that the program doesn't crash.

Comment: Pretty much. You can't write your program so that it does not ever encounter a situation where the programmer cannot make it crash. He can always make things like null pointers. The only thing to do is not do that.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see the disadvantage in disallowing a specific feature which is so to say in the *middle of Murphy and Machiavelli* (and which otherwise has no real advantage). But since it isn't technically possible anyways, I'll stop here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> A a;
>   auto a_moved = std::move(a);   //disallow move of lvalue ref
>   a.do_something();                    //otherwise this could be problematic

The point of std::move() is to take an lvalue and return an rvalue so your move constructor or move assignment can be called. So either make the move constructor and move assignment deleted or your users just have to know what are they doing. Here's some information on std::move() http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move